# Выборка из связи многие ко многим

Tags: sql

Есть таблицы `prod` и `cat` у которых должна быть связь многие ко многим. Единственный метод такой организации который я знаю это создание дополнительной таблицы(`prodcat`), где идентификатору одной строки из одной таблице соответствует другому из другой таблицы. Нужно вывести пары имени prod и имени cat. Можно ли сделать это таким запросом?:

```
SELECT prod.Name, cat.Name 
FROM prodcat
JOIN cat ON prodcat.catId==cat.Id
JOIN prod ON prodcat.prodId==prod.Id
```

Т.е. главный вопрос: работает ли JOIN таким образом, что одну строку изначальной таблицы он записывает в объединенную таблицу несколько копий этой строки?

Comment: 1 - можно, только одинарный = для сравнения нужно использовать. 2 - Дублирующихся пар prod - cat не будет, строки с одинаковыми prod могут быть.

Comment: насчет второго, почему только prod может повторяться, а cat нет?

Comment: cat тоже может повторяться.